# Disable FancyTree Nodes

Tags: javascript, jquery, fancytree

Is there anyway to disable fancytree node? Am using **Select: 2** option along with Ajax call to populate the tree. I get the data from DB and need to show my preselected node selected and disabled as below.
[image]

One option is to set below properties as:

**hideCheckbox: true**

**selected: true**

But this makes the checkbox hidden (as shown in green background below)
[image]

Can't I just disable the node itself(as in 1st pic)? Something similar to diabling of entire tree with below option.

**disabled: false**  (disables the tree)

**UPDATE**

If I use *unselectable* true then I loose the checked box check. ( screen below)

**unselectable: true**

**selected: true**

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no option to disable a node altogether, but you can 'disable' checkboxes using the `unselectable` option.

Comment: If I use `unselectable` true and `selected` true(for showing default check) then I loose the check box checkmark. I have copied the screeshot above.

Comment: This should have been fixed: https://github.com/mar10/fancytree/issues/427 
Are you using a current release?

Comment: Thanks !!  Ya, I was using old version. Updated the CSS, fine now.  Moreover is there a way to send data through JSON to prepopulate the textboxes? I am using the complex demo example. I tried adding a property in json as input1 and tried to access it in `renderColumns` as `node.input1` in similar line to node.key. Didn't worked. Looks like have to make use of `postProcess`.  In between Thanks for the Awesome work :)